# Induced end and monopoles paradox

Tags: electromagnetism

It states that induced end is equal to the change in magnetic flux but we also know that magnetic flux is zero as magnetic monopoles don't exist so how can flux change?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform why is that so this is what my book says

Comment: Does the closed surface here refer to the Gaussian surface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that magnetic monopoles don't exist the divergence of $\mathbf{B}$ is zero so magnetic flux lines cannot have an end - they have to be closed loops. And this is exactly what the flux lines are in e.g. a solenoid. Zero divergence does not mean there cannot be any flux lines.